# Database query syntax issue

Tags: android

I am getting a syntax error in my query:

> near ",": syntax error:

And my query is

```
 select 
     emplnmbr, empname, desigtxt 
 from 
     emp_header 
 where 
     CMPYCODE = 'MMPL' 
     and orguntxt like ('%MARKETING%', '%PERSONNEL&ADMINISTRATION%')
```

If I replace the query with one value y

```
 select 
     emplnmbr, empname, desigtxt 
 from 
     emp_header 
 where 
     CMPYCODE = 'MMPL' 
     and orguntxt like ('%MARKETING%')
```

it works. Someone please help me to find this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple values to check, you need to use `IN` instead of `LIKE`,

```
SELECT
    emplnmbr, empname, desigtxt
FROM
    emp_header
WHERE
    CMPYCODE = 'MMPL'
    AND orguntxt IN ('%MARKETING%', '%PERSONNEL&ADMINISTRATION%')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try

```
SELECT emplnmbr,empname,desigtxt FROM emp_header WHERE CMPYCODE ='MMPL' AND orguntxt IN ('%MARKETING%','%PERSONNEL&ADMINISTRATION%')
```

Use **IN Operator** in **SQLite**. This is used for exact match if you would like to get all the match then refer `@laalto` answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select emplnmbr,empname,desigtxt from emp_header where CMPYCODE = 'MMPL'   and orguntxt IN ('%MARKETING%','%PERSONNEL\&ADMINISTRATION%')
```

**Note:-** Like just excepts one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To combine multiple `LIKE` expressions, use `OR`:

```
orguntxt like '%MARKETING%' or orguntxt like '%PERSONNEL&ADMINISTRATION%'
```

`IN` as mentioned in many other answers has the problem that it is an exact match, not `LIKE` pattern match.